# (#17) User request limit reached - Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am not getting why this is happening, for one of the pages which is being used in our application we keep getting the following error " (#17) User request limit reached".

We are not making a single API call using the tokens for the page, but even on the first attempt we get the same error. What could be the reason behind this, we have checked everything the tokens are page's token and all other API usage.